# Problemas con modelo.edmx

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

queria ver si alguien puede ayudarme con este problema:

Resulta que agregue una nueva tabla a mi BD y ahora quiero actualizar mi modelo.edmx, procedo a actualizarlo dando click derecho, actualizar y luego agrego la nueva tabla, esto me genera una clase de la nueva tabla en el modelo.tt y una clase "public virtual DbSet<Tabla_agregada> Tabla_agregada {get; set;}" en el model.context.cs hasta ahi todo bien, pero en el context no me reconoce la nueva clase agregada, me marca el error "Falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado", si alguien tiene una idea de que podria ser, le agradeceria mucho que me pudiera ayudar.

Comment: ¿Has recompilado el proyecto?

Comment: Si, ya lo habia intentado y nada me funciono, pense que tenia un problema en el codigo, pero al parecer era un "bug" del vs studio, no me queria reconocer la clase agregada, lo que hice para solucionarlo fue cerrar y abrir el vs studio y ya reconocio la clase, aun asi, gracias por responder bro.

Answer (score 0):

Para todo aquel que haya tenido un problema similar, en mi caso al parecer era un "bug" del vs studio, no me queria reconocer la clase agregada, lo que hice para solucionarlo fue cerrar y abrir el vs studio y ya reconocio la clase.